# select data according to Row in Sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image](http://ibin.co/25LJ2OiPlAQ4)
i want to get the whole row i am using this code to get my desired data but its giving me null pointer exception at temp_address1 here is the code

as in mentioned image i want to get the whole row matching phone number. how can i achive that result? phone number is the primary key here
    public class SqliteHelpers extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NotesDatabase.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notesDb";
public static final String NUMBER = "PhoneNumber";
public static final String NOTES = "Note";
public static final String PICTURE = "Picture";

public static final String TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                NUMBER + " TEXT PRIMAY KEY , " +
                NOTES + " TEXT UNIQUE , " +
                PICTURE + " TEXT  " + " ) ";

public SqliteHelpers(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    getReadableDatabase();
    getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    Log.i("DBHelpers", "table created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);

}
```

and second class is

public class DataBaseHelpers {

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDbHelper;
private SqliteHelpers mSqliteHelper;
private Cursor mCursor;

public DataBaseHelpers(Context context) {
    mSqliteHelper = new SqliteHelpers(context);
}


void createNewEntry(String column, String value) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(column, value);
    mDbHelper.insert(SqliteHelpers.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    Log.i("Sqlite", "create entry");
}

void deleteItem(String column, String value) {
    mDbHelper.delete(SqliteHelpers.TABLE_NAME, column + " = ?", new String[]{value});
    Log.i("sqlite", "Entry deleted");
}

void closeDatabase() {
    mSqliteHelper.close();
    Log.i("sqlite", "close database");
}

void retrieveDate(String value) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM notesDb WHERE PhoneNumber ="
            + value;
    mCursor = mDbHelper.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String temp_address = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteHelpers.NUMBER));
            String temp_address1 = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SqliteHelpers.NOTES));
            System.out.println(temp_address);
            System.out.println(temp_address1);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    mDbHelper.close();

}
```

Comment: What does the `=?` syntax mean? Are you sure its not a syntax error?

Comment: no there is no syntax error query is working  fine the the {value } will replaced with ?.

Comment: Do you have _id row? you without this row database can work wrong. And you have to give code where you create database or printscreen from sqlite reader not from Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it just like below code

```
public void rec(int _id){
  String query = "SELECT * FROM notesDb WHERE PhoneNumber ="
        + _id;
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String temp_address = c.getString(0);

        String temp_address1 = c.getString(1);
        System.out.println(temp_address);
        System.out.println(temp_address1);

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
db.close();
}
```

Comment: null pointer exception at  System.out.println(temp_address1);

Comment: @BilalShahid instead of c.getString(1) write properly as c.getString( c.getColumnIndex( String columnName ) );

Comment: yeap @strike is right do something like 
c.getString( c.getColumnIndex( String columnName ) );